# Организация хранения настроек с помощью переменных окружения

Tags: java, git, spring-boot, configuration, настройки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как хранить конфиги (логин/пароль/url к бд) в переменных окружения?

Я сейчас разрабатываю приложение на Spring Boot. Приложение работает с базой данных, поэтому для локального тестирования в файле application.yml прописаны настройки подключения к бд. Однако, коммитить в git их явно не стоит, поэтому сейчас ищу пути как убрать оттуда настройки базы без добавления в игнор всего файла yml.

Я знаю, что одним из решений является просто при запуске приложения для тестировании указывать спрингу другую директорию с файлом конфигов в свойстве `spring.config.location` и эту директорию убрать из-под гита.

Но так же встречала подход с использованием переменных окружения. Но не очень понимаю, как именно это делать.
Понятно, что для приложения в application.properties (yml) это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
some.application.property = ${SOME_APPLICATOPN_PROPERTY}
```

но где должна располагаться сама переменная `SOME_APPLICATOPN_PROPERTY`?
Я предполагаю, что один из вариантов - это в системных переменных ОС, но это как-то слишком глобально, кроме того, у меня нет к ним доступа.
Где еще ее можно хранить?

Comment: (вот примерно поэтому я в принципе осуждаю хранение настроек с помощью переменных окружения)

Comment: Я думаю тут надо использовать профили.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В spring все очень продумано и много возможностей, как задать конфигурацию в разных случаях. Я тут [всю доку](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config) пересказывать не буду (очень рекомендую ее просмотреть хотя бы чтоб понять, какие есть варианты в принципе и разобраться как происходит загрузка параметров конфигурации в принципе, т.е. порядок приоритетов). Я расскажу слегка упрощенно с прицелом на конкретный случай, т.е. то, что касается хранения параметров для локального тестирования.

Допустим в приложении вы используете параметр `my.param` как-то так:

```
@Value("${my.param}")
String myParam;
```

В упрощенном виде для целей этого вопроса spring boot будет искать его в таком порядке:

1. в аргументах командной строки (т.е. его нужно задавать как параметр приложению `java -jar myproject.jar --my.param=xyz`)
2. системное свойство (т.е. параметр при запуске JVM `java -Dmy.param=xyz -jar myproject.jar`)
3. переменная окружения процесса
4. в `application-{profile}.properties` файле(-ах) в путях поиска конфигурации (об этом ниже)
5. в `application-{profile}.properties` файле(-ах) запакованом в ваш jar
6. в `application.properties` файле в путях поиска конфигурации
7. в `application.properties` файле запакованом в ваш jar
8. в файлах из `@PropertySource` аннотаций на ваших классах `@Configuration`

Что значит этот порядок? Это значит, что если вы задали свойство `my.param` в трех местах, скажем в агрументах командной строки, в переменных окружения и в `application.properties`, то в момент обращения к свойству spring возьмет его из командной строки, так как она выше в этом списке. Первое по порядку место, где задано значение, будет использовано.

Это открывает возможности гибко переопределять параметры.

### Профили

Профили позволяют задать какие-то параметры конфигурации в отдельном файле. Какой профиль использовать определяется параметром `spring.profiles.active` (на самом деле там можно задать несколько, но не хочу усложнять и так длинный ответ), который можно задать при старте приложения через командную строку, переменную окружения, системное свойство и т.д.

### Пути поиска конфигурации

По умолчанию spring ищет файлы конфигурации (это нужно в пунктах 4-7 выше) в таком порядке:

1. Поддиректория `config` в текущей директории
2. Текущая директория
3. Директория `/config` в classpath
4. В корне classpath

Это можно настроить, добавить дополнительные пути и т.д.

### Конфигурации для разных окружений

#### Переменные окружения

Тут есть некоторое недопонимание, по-этому объясню.

Во-первых, чтоб использовать переменную окружения в spring boot вам *не* нужно писать чего-то типа в файле:

```
some.application.property = ${SOME_APPLICATOPN_PROPERTY}
```

В месте где вы используете это свойство, скажем через аннотацию `@Value` spring boot автоматически прочитает значение из переменной окружения и будет его использовать вместо значения по умолчанию из `application.properties`. Именно об этом говорит порядок поиска, который я в самом начале привел.

Далее, в переменных окружения нет ничего плохого. Они не являются глобальными или как вы их назвали `системные переменные ОС`, если их вы их не cделаете такими.  Это переменные окружения *процесса*. Тут вы путаете причину и следствие. Один из способов задания переменных окружения это задать их глобально для всех процессов ОС, и вы об этом, наверно, и говорите. Но это делать совсем необязательно.

Правильно делается это так. Создаете файл с нужными переменными, скажем `local.params`.

```
my_param=xyz
other_param=abc
```

Обратите внимание, что в переменных окружения обычно нельзя использовать точки, по-этому их заменяем на подчеркивания, но в самом приложении использует их как обычно, т.е. `my.param` и `other.param`.

Теперь запускаем приложение (тут я предполагаю что у вас linux/unix, для windows я так понимаю, тоже можно [подобным образом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232747/read-environment-variables-from-file-in-windows-batch-cmd-exe)):

```
source local.params                   # читает переменные
export $(cut -d= -f1 local.params)    # экспортирует переменные
java -jar myapp.jar
```

Тут эти переменные не являются глобальными переменными ОС, они установлены только для нашего процесса.

#### Профиль

Создайте файл `application-local.properties` в одном из мест, где спринг ищет (см. выше), и в нем задайте параметры, которые хотите изменить. Все остальные будут браться из `application.properties`. Запускайте приложение так:

```
java -jar myapp.jar --spring.profiles.active=local
```

### Файлы конфигурации и git

Я бы не отметал сходу опцию хранения конфигурации для локального тестирования в системе контроля версия. В этом нет ничего плохого, это даже полезно. Вот приходит новый разработчик и ему не нужно искать, этот самый файл с опциями для локального запуска. Обычно там все равно пароли типа `123` или `password`, т.е. ничего секретного да и данные в тестовой БД, а тем более локальной, вряд ли секретные.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутое объяснение.

Comment: Небольшое уточнение по поводу `чтоб использовать переменную окружения в spring boot вам не нужно писать чего-то типа в файле`. В файле application.prorerty  у меня прописаны настройки spring.datasource.jpa для автоматической конфигурации датасорса, поэтому и стал вопрос именно с файлом

Comment: Я постарался объяснить в ответе, что вам не нужно ничего менять в файле `application.properties` если вы хотите изменить настройки БД с помощью переменной окружения. Достаточно переменной окружения с именем как у параметра в файле (только подчеркивания вместо точек) задать значение перед запуском.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте профили:

рядом с application.yaml положите application-local.yaml в котором задайте все параметры для локального запуска.

При локальном запуске указывайте параметр -Dspring.profiles.active=local

этот файл не надо/можно не помещать в гит.