# Разные .env файлы в зависимости от выбранного окружения

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-boot

Всем привет. Я новичек в spring и kotlin, до этого писал на nest js + ts. Пытаюсь освоить работу с переменными окружения и, в целом, уже использую их в `application.yaml` но хочу сделать возможным подключение разных файлов `.env`, например: `.env.dev`, `.env.prod` в зависимости от каких-нибудь параметров при запуске проекта. Например, как при запуске проекта мы можем использовать параметр `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev/prod` и в зависимости от этого использовать разные `yaml` файлы: `application-dev/prod.yaml`

Файл конфигурации запуска проекта .run/MyCareerApiApplication.run.xml

```
<component name="ProjectRunConfigurationManager">
  <configuration default="false" name="MyCareerApiApplication" type="SpringBootApplicationConfigurationType" factoryName="Spring Boot">
    <option name="ACTIVE_PROFILES" />
    <module name="my_career_api.main" />
    <option name="SPRING_BOOT_MAIN_CLASS" value="ru.my_career.my..." />
    <extension name="net.ashald.envfile">
      <option name="IS_ENABLED" value="true" />
      <option name="IS_SUBST" value="false" />
      <option name="IS_PATH_MACRO_SUPPORTED" value="false" />
      <option name="IS_IGNORE_MISSING_FILES" value="false" />
      <option name="IS_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL_INTEGRATIONS" value="false" />
      <ENTRIES>
        <ENTRY IS_ENABLED="true" PARSER="runconfig" IS_EXECUTABLE="false" />
        <ENTRY IS_ENABLED="true" PARSER="env" IS_EXECUTABLE="false" PATH="src/main/resources/.env.dev" />
      </ENTRIES>
    </extension>
    <method v="2">
      <option name="Make" enabled="true" />
    </method>
  </configuration>
</component>
```

Comment: так  в чем вопрос то?

Comment: Посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1409266/218971

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Спасибо. Постараюсь разобраться с этими источниками переменных. Выглядит так, как будто это поможет

Comment: @Дмитрий  как использовать разные `.env.<profile-name>` файлы в зависимости от `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE`

Answer (score 0):

В один yml файл расписываешь несколько профилей.

```
myconfig:
  name: default-name
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev

myconfig:
  name: dev-name
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: prod

myconfig:
  name: prod-name
```

При запуске проекта указываешь нужный профиль, и у тебя подтянется то значени которое в этом профиле указано.
В классе:

```
// Здесь будет разное имя в зависимости от профиля
@Value(value = "${myconfig.name}")
private String name;
```

Почитать:
[Spring YAML](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml),
[Spting Profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

Comment: Спасибо! Это хороши вариант, но я хотел использовать `.env` файлы для того, чтобы не добавлять их в git. Или `application.yaml` тоже можно не добавлять? Просто, там ведь различные настройки проекта могут быть, которые должны быть публиными + и там же приватные переменные...

Comment: Приватные переменные можно как ссылки указывать и заполнять их во время деплоя или вручную в системные переменные. Например myconfig:name: ${PRIVATE_NAME} и при запуске проекта его вручную заполнять или брать из хранилища (например Spring Vault)

Comment: Кстати в коментах к вопросу оставили ссылку насчет переменных окружения. Эта штука с yml настройками тоже работает